Can I pull an exact subscriber count via the YouTube API?
Per the YouTube API documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels, I can pull a "subscriberCount" value and it is rounded to three significant figures.
Is there a way to pull an accurate (not rounded) channel subscriber number from the API?

Is it for a channel that you own?

Nop. We pull data from YouTube API on behalf of our clients.

Still not resolved...
